# Why reference counting in Python is considered not thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

I read somewhere that python interpreter uses GIL, and of the reasons is that it internally uses reference counting on every object, and reference counting is not thread safe. Could you explain why it is not thread safe?

Also i read that one of the scenarios is that if not GIL, then one of the threads could decrease counter in and if it's zero then it's automatically deallocates the object from the heap, but another thread is still holding pointer to it. How that could happen? Is that because it's possible that both threads when they start holding some object could accidentally execute processor instruction like `counter++` on one variable `counter` at the same time and as a result it's not increased by 2 but only increased by 1?

Comment: CPython uses regular pointers and manual refcounting, not smart pointers.

Comment: Also, reference-counting is not inherently thread-unsafe. For example, C++'s `std::shared_ptr` is a threadsafe reference-counted smart pointer type. Reference counting alone isn't why CPython has a GIL.